# Make parent div behind child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using [jQuery.Gantt](https://github.com/taitems/jQuery.Gantt) in a project and I need do many customization in this plugin.
One of this is pass mouse over an element (blue cells) and show a tooltip (in example I put a title).
I have some divs that "highlight" weekends and these divs is over gantt elements (blue cells)
If I change z-index of cells they will overlay the header (month and day) in horizontal scroll.
I trying to find a way to get the following order: weekend div with **z-index 0**, gantt cells (blue) with **z-index 1** and header with **z-index 2**. I need this order to display the title on gantt cells and use mouseover event on weekend cells.
How can I achieve this with the example below?

```css
.dataPanel {
  outline: 1px solid #DDD;
  background-position-y: 15px;
  background-size: 30px 48px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(153, 152, 153, 0.7) 1px, transparent 1px), linear-gradient(0deg, #E7ECEF 0%, #E7ECEF 53%, #ECF1F4 53%, #ECF1F4 100%);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Verdana, sans-serif';
}

.header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 600;
  width: 241px;
  background: #fff;
  height: 63px;
}

.row {
  float: left;
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin: 0;
}

.dayPosition {
  top: 46px;
}

.monthPosition {
  top: 15px;
}

.day {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
  border-right: 1px solid #DDD;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #007E7A;
}

.row .sa,
.row .sn,
.row .wd {
  height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 29px;
}

.bar {
  background-color: #D0E4FD;
  height: 18px;
  margin: 0 3px 3px 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dataPanel" style="width: 27540px; height: 732px;">
<div class="header">
 <div class="row header monthPosition">
  JAN
 </div>
    <div class="row header dayPosition">
        <div class="row day wd" id="dw-1559098800000" data-repdate="1559098800000">
            <div class="fn-label">WED</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row day wd" id="dw-1559185200000" data-repdate="1559185200000">
            <div class="fn-label">THU</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row day wd" id="dw-1559271600000" data-repdate="1559271600000">
            <div class="fn-label">FRI</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row day sa" id="dw-1559358000000" data-repdate="1559358000000">
            <div class="fn-label">SAT</div>
   <div style="background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.1); height: 673px; width: 30px; bottom: 0px; top: 245px; position: initial;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row day sn" id="dw-1559444400000" data-repdate="1559444400000">
            <div class="fn-label">SUN</div>
            <div style="background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.1); height: 673px; width: 30px; bottom: 0px; top: 245px; position: initial;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row day wd" id="dw-1559530800000" data-repdate="1559530800000">
            <div class="fn-label">MON</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row day wd" id="dw-1559617200000" data-repdate="1559617200000">
            <div class="fn-label">TUE</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row day wd" id="dw-1559703600000" data-repdate="1559703600000">
            <div class="fn-label">WED</div>
        </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div title="Saturday" class="bar" style="top: 63px; left: 90px; width: 29px;"><div class="fn-label">24</div></div>
<div title="Sunday" class="bar" style="top: 63px; left: 120px; width: 29px;"><div class="fn-label">24</div></div>
<div title="Monday" class="bar" style="top: 63px; left: 150px; width: 29px;"><div class="fn-label">24</div></div>
<div title="Tuesday" class="bar" style="top: 63px; left: 180px; width: 29px;"><div class="fn-label">24</div></div>
</div>
```

<sup>[Code in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tiagocrizanto/u58awokb/4/)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add `pointer-events: none;` to the overlay div.

Comment: ritaj thanks and it works perfectly. I read about pointer-events at mozilla mdn but it's not clear. Could you explain what the pointer-events do in the example above?

Comment: `pointer-events: none` says the mouse events (click/hover/etc). will go through the element and will only be registered by the first element *under* it, which *doesn't* have `pointer-events: none` attribute. So, since the overlay is *over* the text, hover is registered by the overlay and not the text `24`, so the hover event doesn't trigger on the text. And hover is needed for tooltip to display. With `pointer-events: none`, though, hover is not registeded by the overlay, it goes through and registers on the text element.